# Automating of pre-generated views

Tags: .net, entity-framework, ef-power-tools

The EF Power Tools have a nice option which is explained here:
"Generates pre-compiled views used by the EF runtime to improve start-up performance. Adds the generated views file to the containing project. If you change your model then you will need to re-generate the pre-compiled views by running this command again."

This feature is pretty amazing hence we can save up to 15 seconds in our bootstrapping. Now my question is: Can I force auto generation while I rebuild the context? According to this, I have the same question about the propagated approach of a separated entity assembly (entities.tt and edmx are in separate assemblies). In both scenarios I have to do the steps manually...

Comment: I finally found a solution on this site: http://blog.3d-logic.com/2012/10/17/entity-framework-6-and-pre-generated-views/